# Find results and Aggregate results differ, despite same query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I am trying to search for people inside of a document that is structured as below. In my "find" function, I will get back 10 results. However, my aggregation returns less than that (approx 7, but seems to depend on the data). I have tried looping through the results of the test_find, and add an '$and' stipulation based on the test_find result's ID, but in some cases it does not return any found results, even when the same query is used in the find() statement.

JSON Object structure:

```
{
    id: "53b563c372f4f85b787b23c8",
    n: "Organization Name"
    fn: "filename.csv"
    p: [ // array of people
        {
            given_name: "John",
            surname: "Smith",
            sc: { // there is actually more data, but only the .sc. data is relevant to search
                g: "John",
                s: "Smith"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Current code:

```
/***** $search_column_query dump ********/
{
    '$and': {
        { "p.sc.s": "Smith" },
        { "p.sc.g": "John" }
    }
}
/**************************************/

$test_find = $db->genealogical_data->find($search_column_query)->limit(10);

// This gets 10 results of documents matching the search query
foreach ($test_find as $result) { 
    var_dump($result["n"]); // "n" is the name
}



// This gets less than 10 (7 in the case of John Smith) results of documents matching the search query
$aggregation = array(
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query ), 
        array( '$limit' => 10 ),
        array( '$unwind' => '$p' ),
        array( '$match' => $search_column_query),
        array( '$group' => array(
            '_id' => '$n',
            'filename' => array( '$first' => '$fn' ),
            'people' => array( '$push' => '$p' )
        )),
        array( '$sort' => array('_id' => 1) ),
    );
$documents_with_results = $db->genealogical_data->aggregate($aggregation);
```

It seems like perhaps my search query is fundamentally wrong, or is being used incorrectly in the aggregation. Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: It would be much easier for most people to help you if your example used actual JSON and the MongoDB shell instead of PHP.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I convered the objects/documents to JSON. I am not very familiar with doing MongoDB work in shell, though, so I left my PHP code to avoid issues with that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the documents which are found by the normal query but not through aggregation?

Comment: By the way, the `$and` is unnecessary. When you put multiple `field:value` pairs into your query, they all have to be fulfilled. But I doubt that this is the reason for your problem.

Comment: The first JSON object is an example of that.

Comment: I will check that out Philipp, thanks. I believe the Aggregation gave me a "this needs to be a non-empty array or object" error when I tried removing that, but I will verify.

Comment: your agg is fine, your find syntax is not correct/not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect query in your `find`.
You should be using [`$elemMatch` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to make sure that your two conditions are matched to the same subdocument/element.

{ "p": { "$elemMatch":
                    { "sc.s": "Smith","sc.g": "John" }
           }
 }

Because you `$unwind` first in aggregation, your query ends up being correct as it's applied to a single element of array automatically.

Comment: what happens when you use the other format (matching s and g separately) is you get back document which has "john brown" and one that has "steve smith" in the same array even though there is no "john smith" in the same element.

Comment: So in the first $match of my aggregation, I should use the $elemMatch instead of what I am doing now? The "find" was done moreso for testing purposes because the data I was getting back was wrong.

Comment: technically, yes, but it doesn't matter as much because all it does now is let through to $unwind some documents that will end up being completely removed by the second match (since they won't have "john smith" in any of the array elements).

Comment: The issue is that when I limit it to 10 after my first match, it will take 10 and 3 of them will be faulty due to the issue you mentioned. So if I will try to switch out the first match to see if that fixes it.

Comment: the "faulty" ones won't be there after the second match, but of course for full correctness you want to use the same first match as your find (but not the second match since you no longer have an array).

Comment: Your explanation of why elemMatch is the solution makes sense. However, I tried doing this and I do not get any results back when I do a find (when I should get results based on the data). Here is the search query I am generating:   

 `array(1) {["p.sc"] => array(1) { ["$elemMatch"] => array(1) { ["g"] => string(9) "Valentine"}}}`   
   
Or in JSON,   

 `{ 'p.sc': '$elemMatch': { 'g': 'Valentine '} }`

Am I doing something incorrect? It is possible that 'g' can have an array of values. Is that what is causing this to give an error?

Comment: Am I doing something incorrect? It is possible that 'g' can have an array of values (though in this case, there is a record with just "Valentine". Is that what is causing this to give an error?

Comment: you only need $elemMatch when you are trying to *match* more than one value inside a single array *element* - you don't need it to match simple array values.

Comment: ah, sorry, I think I misread your document.  I just edited my answer - I misread the document, you need $elemMatch right after the array field "p" in your case.

Comment: I was able to figure that out myself earlier today. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and for editing your answer to the correct one.